# Customize admin interface to modify data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

So i have this models:

1. User model has_one Store
2. Store Model
3. Category/Product belongs_to Store

I want to build an admin interface where user can access if he has a store. While inside the admin interface he should be able to add/modify/delete categories and products but those category will belong to that user's store. And he will only be able to see his store products/categories.

How should i achieve this?

I tried installing RailsAdmin for the administration interface and i have already set up devise for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question here is not "How you should achieve this", but "How you could achieve this".

RailsAdmin + devise and scoping (e.g. @items = current_user.items) would work fine.

Another option is to create a scaffold for User-Categories/Products, using the same scope as above and authentication. Using this approach you will have to do it from scratch. That costs time at first, but in the long term, if you want to add more complex things to your admin interface, it's relatively easier to extend than using already-built solution (like RailsAdmin).

Comment: Scoping works fine, but how can i restrict the records shown in the list action?

Comment: By restrict, you mean to show only current_user store's products/categories?

Comment: Yes, how can i do that? I was looking at creating a scope, but i couldn't do current_user from the scope

Comment: scope :of_user, -> (user) { user.products }
And then in your controller: @products = Product.of_user(current_user)

Comment: So does that mean i have to modify the list controller? if so how do i do it.